# Adding shortcode to Wordpress Template File

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am attempting to add the following shortcode to a template file at my site using do shortcode and I can't seem to get it working correctly for some reason.  Any idea how this needs to be formatted to working correctly?

```
[nws_alerts zip='<? echo $decoded2['ob']['zip']; ?>' state="" display="basic"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have PHP inside the shortcode like that. It would need to be called like this:

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode( '[nws_alerts zip=' . $decoded2["ob"]["zip"] . ' state="" display="basic"]' );
?>
```